# Why isn't my electric hot water tank producing hot water?

Tags: hot-water

We just bought a trailer and had the water turned on. We have cold water coming out of hot water side in kitchen and bathroom. What could this be? Also we have good water pressure in the bathroom but very low pressure in the kitchen. What could cause this? We checked the breakers and it is on. HELP!! We are not knowledgeable at all on home improvements.

Comment: Was was the hot water temperature & pressure like when you inspected the place before you bought it? How significant are the differences?

Comment: Is it a trailer home or a camper?

Comment: Electric or gas water heater?  Unusually fat electric cables running to it?  Or a hard pipe and an exhaust stack?  Is there a switch on the water heater?  (don't just turn on a gas water heater without following the light-pilot procedure).

Answer (score 1):

Hot water will depend on the recovery time of the heater. Being off, it will take longer than normal since there is no residual heat. Does this water heater have any adjustable settings, an off, vacation or hold, or adjustable thermostat? I suggest waiting about half a day and see what it does. If it still is cold water temp, you have a wiring or element issue. If it is warm, wait until the next day and test again. If it's hot, you're good, still warm? Check elements or settings (if it has any).

As for pressure, have the water off, and I assume drained from the plumbing, you may have sediment washed into the aerator or valves. Pull your aerator of each sink, if it can be, and check for sediment. Clean and reinstall. If that doesn't help, try to open and close the valves under the sink a few times, check the aerator again.